# Xcode Swift multiply two integer variables and store value in label text

Tags: xcode, swift, variables, int, multiplication

I working on a project using Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.  I know some of this will change when I go to Swift 2. I have a couple of string variables that are assigned from a value stored in NSUserDefaults.  I then convert them to integers and add them together to be assigned to a label's text:

```
self.redKidTotalO.text = "\(sundayRedIncoming.toInt()!+mondayRedIncoming.toInt()!)"
    //Convert label text to integer for math
```

After that, I take the label text value and convert to an integer to be used in multiplication of two integer variables:

```
    redIntStarTotal = (self.redKidTotalO.text)!.toInt()
```

I then want to take another value from NSUserDefaults and store it into an integer variable and multiply the two together and set a new label text to that:

```
var paymentIncoming: String!
var paymentIncomingInt: Int!
var paymentMultiply:Int!
var paymentMathTotalConvert: String!
var redIntStarTotal: Int!

if let KEYpaymentMoneyAmountIsNotNill = amountDefaults.objectForKey("KEYpaymentMoneyAmount") as? String {
    paymentIncoming = (amountDefaults.objectForKey("KEYpaymentMoneyAmount") as! String)

    //Take String 'paymentIncoming' and convert to Integer for math
    paymentIncomingInt = paymentIncoming.toInt()
    println(paymentIncomingInt)

    //Do math
    paymentMultiply = paymentIncomingInt * redIntStarTotal
    println("Multiply: \(paymentMultiply)")

    //Take integer 'paymentMultiply' and convert to String for label text
    paymentMathTotalConvert = toString(paymentMultiply)

    // Load payment amount into labels
    self.redPaymentO.text = "(\(paymentMathTotalConvert) cents)"
}
```

Testing this and performing println() on 'paymentIncomingInt' I get to this point ok.  After that and I type the code for the multiplication, it gives me the error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 
(lldb)

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the two variable integers to multiply together and display that value into label text? Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `redIntStarTotal`?

Comment: Also, do you know what it means that you're declaring variables as `String!` and `Int!` instead of `String` and `Int`?

Comment: log value of redIntStarTotal before using it.

Comment: redIntStarTotal is a value of a couple integer variables from another view controller.  I wasn't aware of the difference between the ! and ? on the variables.